# UserControl Load event not fired

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have WinForms application. My Form derived class has UserControl derived class.
I simply put several controls into one UserControl to simplify reuse. The `Load` event of `UserControl` is not fired. Do I have to set some property?

Comment: Please show the (outline of) your code.

Comment: Have you subscribed for onload events from each usercontrol in your class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try overriding the [OnLoad() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.onload.aspx) in your UserControl.  From MSDN:

> The OnLoad method also allows derived
>   classes to handle the event without
>   attaching a delegate. This is the
>   preferred technique for handling the
>   event in a derived class.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code to run on load goes here 

    // Call the base class OnLoad to ensure any delegate event handlers are still callled
   base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ashley, it works perfectly. Have you any idea why the OnLoad event don't work in some cases and when overriding OnLoad, it works everytime?

Answer (score 3):

There wouldn't be any special properties you need to set for a UserControl's events to fire. You have one of 2 ways to subscribe to the event. In the Properties (property grid) select the events list...double-click at the Load property. All the necessary pieces of code will be put in place, and your cursor will be waiting for you at the proper method.

The second method is subscribing to the event like so:

```
public MyMainForm( )
{
    InitializeComponents();
    myUserControl.Load += new System.EventHandler(myUserControl_Load);
}

void myUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((UserControl)sender).Name + " is loaded.");
}
```

Comment: I do exactly what you code here, but that doesnt work at all. If I instead override the OnLoad it works...

Comment: well...it looks like MSDN knows better, so I'd go with that, too.

Comment: the Load+= has to appear before InitializeComponents()

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the Load event to stop firing is when you have a parent of your control that does something like this

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
     //do something
    }
```

you always need to make sure to do this

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
     //do something
     base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```