# how to write code that runs AFTER datagrid finished rendering?

Tags: winforms, user-controls, datagridview, onload

The following code of updating the custom column "hello" works perfectly when the grid is on form and this code is on form_load. BUT when the grid is on a usercontrol and the code is on UserControl1_Load  it doesn't update the grid (unless I add this code inside a button click etc. ) - I blame microsoft!

I'm trying to find a workaround to run that code after grid finished rendered because then it works (for example when I write it on button_click event), any ideas?

```
List<MyClass> all_customers = new List<MyClass>();

   all_customers.Add(new MyClass() { MyProperty = 2, MyProperty2 = "33" });
   all_customers.Add(new MyClass() { MyProperty = 2, MyProperty2 = "33" });
   all_customers.Add(new MyClass() { MyProperty = 2, MyProperty2 = "33" });

   dataGridView1.DataSource = all_customers;

   DataGridViewTextBoxColumn c = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   c.Name = "hello";
   c.HeaderText = "hello";
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add(c);
   dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["hello"].Value = "text2";
```

Comment: Try overriding OnLoad() in your UC, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220483/usercontrol-load-event-not-fired)

Comment: @Bismark - thank u but it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
  {
   dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["hello"].Value = "pp";

  }
```

This did the trick. from some reason it didn't work for me before, but when I stripped my code from all complex code lines it did work. oh well